# How to add shadow to Frame on Xamarin.Forms - Android?

Tags: android, .net, xamarin.forms

I need to add shadow effect to `Frame` on **Android**. 
Shadow has to be only **under and right** from the `Frame`.
How could I do it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Tried this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505696/xamarin-forms-shadow-on-frame-in-android/42527548#42527548 . Don't forget to give padding.